# What is so demonic about Welsh-language television that Gaiman&Pratchett decided Crowley invented it himself?

Tags: terry-pratchett, neil-gaiman, good-omens

In Good Omens, Welsh-language television is said to be one of Crowley's proud and modern acheivements. Why is that? I gathered by the context that it was BAD, but have no idea how an entertainment business could in any way render people so miserable..Is it a language barrier thing?

> Spending years picking away at one soul. Admittedly it was craftsmanship, but you had to think differently these days. Not big, but wide. With five billion people in the world you couldn't pick the buggers off one by one any more; you had to spread your effort. But demons like Ligur and Hastur wouldn't understand. They'd never have thought up Welsh-language television, for example. Or valueadded tax. Or Manchester.

Comment: It's an in-joke about Brit culture. With *Good Omens*, it's ALWAYS an in-joke about Brit culture.

Comment: As a native to the Greater Manchester area, I can agree with the sentiment... I might be fond of the place but it has certain qualities to it that not even a demon would think to inflict upon humanity. :P The road layout, for a start.  Take a look at this map if you don't believe me: https://goo.gl/maps/U7WcXQ8mP1Q2 ... don't even get me started on MUFC vs MCFC.

Comment: Also, did I mention that Manchester weather is particularly efficient in it's ability to make people miserable?  The North West might not be the wettest area of the country, but I think we stand a good chance in a contest of "the most types of unpleasant weather" heh.

Comment: @Kaithar I'd like to enter Sheffield.

Comment: @Kaithar: I'm told Manchester became a big city *because* of the damp climate. It stops yarn from fraying as it's being worked, which was good for the textile industry. A demon would never have thought of that.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit That's possible but we were also a massive coal town which is very location specific heh.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At an educated guess, Pratchett and Gaiman are referring to the [creation of S4C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S4C), the Welsh-language TV channel which began broadcasting in 1982. (*Good Omens* was published in 1990 and [mostly written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Omens#Origins_and_authorship) in 1988.)

At this time, the UK had a total of four broadcast television channels. [Channel 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_5_(UK)) was not launched until 1997.

S4C's English-language counterpart, [Channel 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_4), was launched at the same time in the rest of the UK. Channel 4 was known for seeking out "cooler" and edgier programming than its more staid counterparts at the BBC and ITV. Welsh viewers missed out on some of this in favour of Welsh-language programming.

Furthermore, Welsh content was (and is) not generously funded, so production values tend to be low, which might have annoyed Welsh speakers. Conversely, non-Welsh speakers in Wales might have been annoyed that of the four available channels, one was occupied by incomprehensible Welsh programming.

Comment: S4C was actually a bilingual channel from launch until 2010: it carried English-language programming (timeshifted from Channel 4) in some off-peak timeslots. After the digital switchover, Both Channel 4 and S4C could be received throughout Wales, so S4C became a Welsh-only station.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Royal Canadian Bandit's answer, there is another possible explanation:

The establishment of S4C as a Welsh-language fourth TV channel was a very political issue. Prior to its establishment, the existing broadcasters (BBC and ITV) had produced some Welsh-language programming for the region, but it was often broadcast in inconvenient timeslots. Campaigners wanted a dedicated station that would give priority to Welsh-language programming instead, and had been very vocal throughout the 1970s.

In the 1979 general election, both main political parties promised to establish a Welsh-language TV channel in their manifestos. The victorious Conservative party had a change of heart once in office, and started watering down their proposals. The leader of the Welsh nationalist party Plaid Cymru, [Gwynfor Evans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gwynfor_Evans), threatened to go on a hunger strike until the Prime Minister agreed to keep her manifesto promise. She relented, and the Welsh fourth channel S4C actually launched one day ahead of the English-language Channel 4, probably for political reasons.

**There was therefore a significant amount of argument, anger and "misery" around the establishment of the channel in the first place.**

(For further reading, an archived article [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090304205140/http://www.transdiffusion.org/emc/seefour/wales.php) gives some more background to the development of Welsh-language television up to the creation of S4C.)